# The main or a main

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

I think the sentence "we have reached a main result of ..." is perfectly OK. But the grammar check says it should be "the main" instead. I wonder which one is correct.

Comment: Tell me, do you rely upon grammar checkers in your own language to tell you what is correct, or do you use your own judgment?

Comment: I sometimes use grammar checkers but I find it is (often) wrong. So I also trust my own judgement.

Comment: English is no different.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I think the meaning is that in English grammar checkers are also often wrong. If so, I agree.

Comment: Yup, that's the meaning. You can't rely on grammar checkers, period.

Comment: It's frequently the case that examples of grammatically sound constructions are also rare or, at least, most unusual: Google Books Ngram Viewer shows **a main result** to be one of these. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+main+result%2Cthe+main+result&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20main%20result%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20main%20result%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see anything ungrammatical about

> we have reached a main result of ...

Indeed in some contexts use of "the" instead might be incorrect.

Computer grammar checkers are not yet good enough to be relied on for decisions, in my view. The most they are good for is to highlight text for human examination and decision.